# Specflow regex matching - overloading of definitions

Tags: c#, regex, specflow

I would like to have overloaded step definitions in Specflow grammar. Similar to this. Could you help me to write correctly the regexes, as these doesn't work together now. Thank you

```
[Given(@"^Click on ""(.*)""$")]

And Click on "Ok"



[Given(@"^Click on ""(.*)"" in \$""(.*)""$")]

And Click on "Search" in $".someselector"
```

Comment: That will likely lead to an ambiguous step error.  Both "OK and "Search" in $".someselector" will match the first sentence.  You want to use (OK|Cancel) for the first so that it doesn't match any string that it wants.

Comment: btw, try using single quotes around parameters instead of double.  It makes the regex cleaner and from what I've read is the default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution that should probably work sufficiently would be to replace your `(.*)`'s with `([^"]*)` (instead of 'any character', 'any character that is not a `"`).

A slightly better solution might be counting your `"`'s to ensure that you match the opening and ending quotation mark. Most probably you won't need to, but just in case you may want to read up on the concept of [balancing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html).